# Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional and wdksetup for wdk8.1

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wdk, kmdf, minifilter, umdf

I have installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Professional and wdksetup for wdk8.1 but i couldn't find 'Visual C++ > Windows Driver > WDF' in the 'New Project' dialog box. I have to develop a minifilter driver. Guide me am lost